# Lubutnu 16.04 freezes for sometime

Tags: lubuntu, freeze

I had installed lubuntu 16.04 in my Old computer which have

- Intel Pentium 4 processor
- 934 MB RAM
- 2 hard disks.master is 160 GB and mounted as `/` and slave is 80 GB mounted as `/home` (both are ext3)

Windows 7 & was running fine in it but it was not legal copy,thus I had installed lubuntu as only and primary OS in my computer. When I was installing the lubuntu,it froze too many times and I was rebooting it and try to install it again and again but after some time i gave up and open my laptop and try to google the problem,but then suddenly it started installing again(after approximately 10 to 15 minutes)!!!!After installing the lubuntu I boot in it and I had noticed that when I try to listen the music it froze for some time (5 to 10 minutes).It Also freezes when i try to upgrade it. please help me.(Also sound quality is too poor ,should I ask new question about it?!!).After some time it works normal again.

Also my father bought this computer 7 years ago for 40,000 Rs.It have Intel mother bored.

Comment: Your computer may have been worth 40,000 Rs. when it was purchased but it is worth far less than that now, perhaps even nothing because it is wasting your time.

Comment: try using Xubuntu. It's slightly fatter but I use it on my 12-year-old laptop with a P4. It actually outperforms a 6-year-old laptop running Lubuntu with twice the memory.